# Is there a way to detach running remote ssh script in PyCharm?

Tags: ssh, pycharm, detach

I use **remote shh** interpreter in **PyCharm** regularly, using the configured deployment. I often run remote programs from PyCharm GUI (using F5 key), that takes hours to complete (e.g. training a deep net). This unfortunately means that any network outage causes running script to exit and I have to run the script over again. Is there a way to detach the running script so it keeps running? In the sense similar to what **screen** or **nohup** is doing? I know I can run it in screen manually via ssh, but it is a bit inconvenient.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your existing code for launching this script. It would also be helpful to know what the script does--what output it produces, and whether you need to capture the output or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found out that this feature is not implemented yet. There is however a suggested [workaround](https://medium.com/@hooshaya/train-your-model-in-background-and-disconnect-from-pycharm-remote-debug-run-over-ssh-with-nohup-563cb778a1e9)